# How to correctly read a classification report?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall, confusion-matrix

Firstly, is there a difference between model performance and it's accuracy? If yes, what exactly?

Secondly, what can I interpret from this `classification_report` of my model.
Eg: The model's ability to predict 1 is `87%` or `51%`. Also, will accuracy be a good metric to evaluate as there's a major class imbalance but this class imbalance is of test data and not training, so I'm confused here as well?

[image]

I'm confused, is the model good a predicting 1 or 0

Comment: Well not really. If you predict for example cancer and want to know if someone has cancer, then by a recall of 0.36, it is better to flip a coin. You need to try some undersampling or oversampling techniques or class weights for the models. Which model do you have use?

Answer (score 3):

1. you decide whether accuracy is a good metric to evaluate model performance based on your knowledge of your data and your aim (for example if your aim is to classify rare diseases accuracy is usually a bad metric, but that is not your case)
2. if your model says an element is 1, then 87% of times he is right (not bad)
3. where your model fails a bit is recall on 1, which means he only detected as 1 36% of all 1s available. so if your aim is to build a diagnostic test, where 1 means ill, you should improve the recall of your model
4. f1-score is a quantity that tries to combine precision and recall in one number to penalize models that despite having high accuracy for example have low recall for one class
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall